# Error with clogit function in R

Tags: r, clogit

I am using the clogit function for the matched data with the disease-outcome and categorical predictor. However R returns message "X matrix deemed to be singular;"

I saw posts where similar situations were discussed however in my case when I made dummy variables corresponding to the categories, they don't correlate. Also no correlation with the outcome was found. "Ideal classification" which was previously discussed here is not the case as well.

In fact, when I fit logistic regression I get coefficients for levels of categorical predictor of about 0, strongly insignificant. Only intercept is significant.

Have anybody got an idea why could this be happening?